# How to show a few windows with picture in Scilab?

Tags: image, scilab, imshow, display

I'm using the `imshow()` function in Scilab. I can show one picture. However, how do I display a few windows with graphics.

Answer (score 1):

To open several graphics windows, use [`show_window`](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/show_window.html). The one created by default has number 0. Additional windows numbered 1,2,3 are created by the example below, each containing a separate plot.

```
x = linspace(-1,1)
plot(x, sin(x))
show_window(1)
plot(x, cos(x))
show_window(2)
plot(x, tan(x))
show_window(3)
plot(x, exp(x))
```

---

Often, it is more convenient to use [`subplot`](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/subplot.html) for combining several plots in one window. The arguments are: number of  rows, number of columns, and the number of the subplot to which the graphic output will be directed (counting row by row). Example:

```
x = linspace(-1, 1)
subplot(2, 2, 1)
plot(x, sin(x))
subplot(2, 2, 2)
plot(x, cos(x))
subplot(2, 2, 3)
plot(x, tan(x))
subplot(2, 2, 4)
plot(x, exp(x))
```

[image: plots]

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I make operations (thresholding, filtering, etc.) on picture (jpg,png,btm). Can I use show_window() function to my operations?

Comment: It shouldn't matter what you do with images. `show_window` opens a new graphics window to which graphic output will now be directed.